# Load balancing and authentication

Tags: architecture

Lets say we have a running our web application on three nodes. And lets say we have load balancer. How do load balanced systems handle sessions?

Because it's is should be very common scenario, when user authenticates, makes one request and that request was handled by node-1, and next request will be handled with node-2. And time delta could be very small.

Does session stores on all nodes are syncing very fast or there is some other approaches?

Comment: That is the very reason why stateless services are preferred. Get rid of your sessions ;)

Comment: @plalx But how statles services handle authentication problem? Even with tokens we need to store and share them. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions can be shared across multiple instances using a shared session db. Redis cache is one example for such purposes.

syncing session store on all nodes is also an approach. But this requires fast replication and can be difficult to scale. And failover cannot be guaranteed.

Authentication should be handled by a central server. Any number of request serving nodes can use it.